# If division by zero do not show error

Tags: php, codeigniter, math, division

Is there a way to not show an error when division is by zero?

I have a site where members can see their total earnings in their user area. When a member has no earnings then it shows the division-by-zero-error in userarea for that member which I dont want.

```
<td><center><?php echo (($completed->rate / 100) * $completed->number_urls) + (($completed->rate / 100) * $completed->number_urls)/(4); ?></center></td>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can always suppress the errors using the '@' for example @( (1*100) / 0 )

Comment: don't suppress errors using `@`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test like this:

```
if( isset( $completed->rate ) && $completed->rate != 0 ){
    echo (($completed->rate / 100) * $completed->number_urls) + (($completed->rate / 100) * $completed->number_urls)/(4);    
}else{
    echo '0';
}
```